# Ubuntu network share fails to mount, can't get to command prompt on boot?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, mount, network-shares, fstab

One of my network shares is down, which isn't a big deal, but now my Ubuntu instance fails to boot properly. On boot it will display the screen giving me the option to skip the mount, or do a manual mount, however it won't respond to keyboard input at this point.  Pressing escape (I believe it is escape) gets away from the splash screen and shows the boot log, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd> works, but nothing else.

The last status message is "mountall: mount //mydrive/ failed with status code 1" yet I can't bring up command prompt or anything.

How do I get to the prompt so I can edit fstab and delete the share? I've tried to ssh and vnc into the machine, but it doesn't respond to the requests. I can ping it and see the shared folders on the machine, so some modules have loaded.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `init=/bin/bash` on the kernel command line to boot directly into a shell, with no service running whatsoever. With the default bootloader settings, you may need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make the boot menu appear; press <kbd>Shift</kbd> as soon as the BIOS has initialized the keyboard and hold it until the boot menu appears. At the menu, edit the line beginning with `kernel` to add `init=/bin/bash` at the end, then boot.

Once you have the bash prompt, run the following commands:

```
mount /proc
mount -o remount,rw /
vi /etc/fstab  # or whatever your favorite editor is
mount -o remount,ro /
reboot -f
```

(By the way, not being able to skip the network mount sounds like a bug.)

Comment: Worked beautifully, nice to know how to get bash in case something like this happens again. Thanks!